# Stuck on "/dev/sda5 clean" screen, how can I fix this?

Tags: boot, drivers

Im dual booting ubuntu with windows 10, and when I choose ubuntu, my computer gets stuck in this screen. O let it sit like this for 12 hours and it doesmt go away.

It happened after I tried installing Amd Radeon drivers following [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) guide.

I had trouble at getting into video group and tried few times. It wouldnt show up when I run groups again.

Thanks for your attention.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you had trouble getting into the video group....what kind of trouble?

Comment: @George It wouldnt show up when I run groups again. As I said. Tough that may be normal because I tried running groups again before logging in and out and didnt see video there.

Comment: Can you access the Boot Menu when booting?

Comment: @George Yes I can